# How to show a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error to user

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, network-programming

My app allows users to specify a server name which is where their installation of our api is. This is so the rest of the app can make calls to that endpoint.

However, I need to display an error message to if we get an error like ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and it seems that I'm not able to catch this as an error in javascript.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

What're you using to make the call to the endpoint? if you're using fetch you don't have an exception, the response is an object with a property error in true and the error messages.

```
response = {
   error: true,
   data: { message: 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED', code: 404 }
}
```

If you're using axios, you have to make something like this:

```
axios.post('/formulas/create', {
    name: "",
    parts: ""
})
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: But when axios try to fetch bad URL he throw an error, and in catch how to determinate that this error not resolved ?
`{"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network Error\n    at createError `
For example I if we have no an internet connection or bad domain name error in axios will be the same.